# I made customize horizontal stepper in flutter and it's not scrolled till the end

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Does anyone know how to make my stepper scrollable in vertically, it actually could scroll but it doesn't scrolling till the end of the page length

**The stepper:**

```
    MainScaffold(
      title: appBarTitle,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        width: width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Row(
              children: _lineViews(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: _titleViews(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: stepPanels())
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: _buttonControls(currentStep, context),
    );
```

I put the stepper's content inside expanded listview, and I already add `shrinkwrap` & `physics` into it, when I call this customizable widget on another class, it can't be scrolled till the end of the page

```
        Steps(
            content: Obx(
              () {
                if (controller.loading.value) {
                  return const LoadingProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        controller.loading.value
                            ? const LoadingProgressIndicator()
                            : _doctorProfile(),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        const ClinicTypeToggle(),
                        const SizedBox(height: 100.0),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

that is the content that I want to scroll

Comment: are you doing horizontal scroll on column or listview?

Comment: From Steps widget remove the last sizebox then try it